# How to crop images from gallery and camera

Tags: android, android-camera, gallery, crop

i know there is alot of diffrent tutorials online to teach u how to implement cropping, but im having trouble applying cropping function to my project. im building an OCR application, i used the onActivityresult to perform my OCR. i do not know how to add the cropping function into my code. Please help.

This is my button to press for gallery.

```
  findViewById(R.id.b1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GALLERY);
            }
        });
```

And this is my camera button.

```
findViewById(R.id.imageButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String filename = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, filename);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
        });
```

This is my onActivityresult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_GALLERY:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    inspect(data.getData());
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CAMERA:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (imageUri != null) {
                        inspect(imageUri);
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                break;
        }
    }
```

because im passing my image into "inspect" class, how do i implement the cropping before passing them into inspect ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not do much work in activity result, you can start a new thread to do complicated things and it's easy to do this using rxjava. Do this in you case:

```
Observable.just(imgUri)
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .map(uri -> MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri))
          .map(bitmap -> getCroppedImgAndReturnItsUri(bitmap))
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(uri -> {inspect(uri);}, throwable -> {})
```

And don't forget to dispose this disposable on your activity stop.

Comment: thankyou. im quite new at this,  where should i paste this code ?  and what do you mean by "don't forget to dispose this disposable on your activity stop."?

Comment: You can paste this code when you get the image uri like "case REQUEST_CAMERA:". And you can find rxjava doc here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava . "dispose this disposable" is like you should cancel the callback when you exit the activity.

Comment: im sorry but is there any other simpler ways that i could implement this ? im quite confused